# How can I have audio in Google Dictionary's pop-up bubble?

Tags: sound, google-chrome, dictionary

Can someone show me how to have audio in Google Dictionary? I can double-click on a word and a small bubble would pop up with the definition. But I do not have the pronunciation sound.

But if I click "More>>" to have Google Dictionary open on a new tab, then I can have the audio just fine.

Am I missing some java plugins or something? I have Lubuntu 12.04. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dictionary-bubble-by-good/mfembjnmeainjncdflaoclcjadfhpoim

if you're still facing the same problem then sure, you don't have Flash installed.

to install Flash use the following command.

```
sudo apt-get install gnash mozilla-plugin-gnash
```

Gnash is an alternative to Adobe Flash.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the answer. This is what I did: I used Synaptic and installed the chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra package. Now I can hear the pronunciation of a word if I click on the speaker icon in the pop-up bubble.